# How does systemd-tmpfiles work?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, sysfs

I'm trying to change the value of `/sys/bus/usb/devices/4-3/power/wakeup` at every boot (4-3 according to my `lsusb`, it's the keyboard ID).

The default value is:

```
# cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/4-3/power/wakeup
enabled
```

The classic "online" editing works as expected:

```
# echo disabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/4-3/power/wakeup
# cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/4-3/power/wakeup
disabled
```

I'm using a systemd distro so I'd like to use [the systemd-way to edit "temp files"](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html)

I have created the following file:

```
# cat /etc/tmpfiles.d/disable-usb-wakeup.conf 
w /sys/bus/usb/devices/4-3/power/wakeup - - - - disabled
```

but after every boot I still have the default value in this file (i.e. enabled)

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

Here another test:

```
# cat /etc/tmpfiles.d/scheduler.conf 
w /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler - - - - deadline
```

and this one works fine! After booting I get:

```
# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler 
noop [deadline] cfq
```

(the default one was the cfq scheduler)

So, why this one works and the other one doesn't?

- Because `/sys/bus/usb/devices/4-3/power/wakeup` is a symlink to `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.1/usb4/4-3/` ?
- Because `/sys/bus/usb/devices/4-3/power/wakeup` contains only one word? (i.e. no spaces)

Comment: Great question, but nobody is answering it. Regardless of whether it is the *right* thing to do, questions should be answered with the approach, 'if I *were* to do this, how *would* I?" I actually needed the answer to this and found this. Anybody care to answer on the actual question?

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe `tmpfiles.d` is the proper way to go here. You really should do the `udev` rules. Look:

```
udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/scsi_host/host*

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/ata1/host0/scsi_host/host0':
    KERNEL=="host0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="scsi_host"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{unchecked_isa_dma}=="0"
    ATTR{state}=="running"
    ATTR{cmd_per_lun}=="1"
...
    ATTR{ahci_host_version}=="10200"
    ATTR{prot_guard_type}=="0"
    ATTR{eh_deadline}=="off"
    ATTR{link_power_management_policy}=="max_performance"
    ATTR{host_busy}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/ata1/host0':
    KERNELS=="host0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""
...
```

And it goes on, walking up the parent device tree. But consider that, using just the information above, you can do:

```
KERNEL=="host[0-5]", SUBSYSTEM=="scsi_host", ATTR{link_power_management_policy}="min_power"
```

And I believe that does it for the majority of your script. You'll want to put the above after rule 60, I think. And really, you should do this for the rest - just the `sleep` bit in your script is reason enough - it implies a race condition. `udev` is the one adding and setting these parameters - it's the one that populates `sysfs`. Just ask it to do the work it is already doing.

And for your keyboard you should definitely do the same - and the backlight. Just get the information you need about these devices from `udevadm`, write some rules and `udevadm test` them.

Comment: At https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_saving#SATA_Active_Link_Power_Management there is a similar example `ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="scsi_host", KERNEL=="host*", ATTR{link_power_management_policy}="min_power"`. Would you please explain why your UDEV rule here doesn't include an ACTION statement and isn't comma separated?

Comment: @ProBackup - probably cause mine is broken. I don't think the `ACTION` bit is necessary though.

Comment: To test the link_power_management_policy for example: `udevadm test /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/scsi_host/host0/`

Comment: This is indeed the proper way to go. People should really use udev rules in cases where synchronisation to device addition/removal events is required.

Answer (score 2):

[ My original idea that this could be because systemd-tmpfiles uses stream I/O and was not intended to be used with proc or sys is [wrong](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2012-September/006576.html). My 2nd hypothesis, about the significance of a newline, was also wrong... ]

I just looked at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` and there's a couple of bits in there that may be of interest:

```
[Unit]
Description=Recreate Volatile Files and Directories
Documentation=man:tmpfiles.d(5)
DefaultDependencies=no
Wants=local-fs.target
After=systemd-readahead-collect.service systemd-readahead-replay.service local-fs.target
Before=sysinit.target shutdown.target

[...]

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemd-tmpfiles --create --remove
```

The 'Wants', 'After', and 'Before' give some information about when this happens; I would think your device is registered by this point, but there could be something *subsequent* that resets the sysfs value.

The most helpful bit is the ExecStart line, because that's the actual command that accounts for this service.  This is actually mentioned in `man systemd-tmpfiles`:

> For example, during boot the following command line is executed to
>   ensure that all temporary and volatile directories are removed and
>   created according to the configuration file:
>
> systemd-tmpfiles --remove --create

So, to test this, set the sysfs value to "enabled" and then try running `systemd-tmpfiles --create` which will process your 'w' directive in /etc/tmpfiles.d.  **If that works** (it should!), then you know that the systemd-tmpfile method is fine, just you have to do it later in the boot process, perhaps with:

```
Requires=multi-user.target
After=multi-user.target
```

Which means writing your own service file; if for some reason it doesn't work, you can always write a service file for a script to do it with `echo`.

Comment: I don't think that systemd can't write on virtual file systems. Using tmpfiles on `/proc/acpi/wakeup` works fine, for example (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Temporary_files)

Comment: @ital : I was probably wrong about that, but if you are still frustrated try my second hypothesis above.

Comment: Using `echo -n disabled > /sys/...` works, so probably the newline presence doesn't care in this case. But tmpfiles is still not working, I've tried both `disabled\n` and `"disabled\n"`

Comment: I have edited the first post with another test and some hypothesis.

Comment: @ital Sheesh. Okay, pretty sure my 3rd guess is the lucky one, so I edited that in above again, lol.  If after that you need the basics for writing and registering a systemd service, ask a new question and maybe reference this one; I can explain it without all this clutter, we will get some input from others, and the question can stand for posterity (I don't see any here yet that address this very well).

Comment: We got the point! Running `systemd-tmpfiles --create` *works*. I'll start a new question for the .service file. Thank you.

Comment: Bad news :(
If I run `systemd-tmpfiles --create`, *all* the directives in `/etc/tmpfiles.d/` and `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/` files are processed. This means that `/run/nologin` is re-created (by `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd.conf`) and any not-root user can't login anymore. (https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1175975) This is a problem, for example when I suspend my pc.
I should remove `/run/nologin` explicity, but this is becoming too much hackish. I think that the `echo` solution within a script called by a .service is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I learned recently the hard way that /etc/tmpfiles.d is processed before /sys is populated so you have to create the proper udev rules so they are enable whenever the devices shows up or... go the dirty way (but if you ask me, a more flexible one) and create a service that runs an script with the commands to write into /sys.

Take a look here for an example on how to create such script, https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=148170 which you can fill with something like:

```
#### #!/bin/sh

sleep 2

#### # Enforce energy tweaks provided by PowerTop
echo min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy;
echo min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host1/link_power_management_policy;
echo min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host2/link_power_management_policy;
echo min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host3/link_power_management_policy;
echo min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host4/link_power_management_policy;
echo min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host5/link_power_management_policy;
echo 1 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save;
echo auto > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:7f:00.1/power/control;
echo auto > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.1/power/control;

...

echo 4880 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness

...
```

Comment: Could you post a link confirming your statement about tmpfiles & /sys/ population order? Here is [another Arch thread](http://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=8243#p44248) where tmpfiles were suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit overkill, but in my case both methods mentioned in other answers were failing. The `tmpfiles.d` [makes the changes before the `/sys/` entries are populated](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Temporary_files) and the `udev` method did not find the entry (which was a virtual network device `br0`).
As such, I created a new service file.
Just create a new file `/etc/systemd/system/disable-usb-wakeup.service` and place the following inside:

```
[Unit]
Description=Set multicast snoop to off
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c "echo disabled >> /sys/bus/usb/devices/4-3/power/wakeup"
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/usr/bin/bash -c "echo enabled >> /sys/bus/usb/devices/4-3/power/wakeup"
StandardOutput=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now, to make sure this unit is started on every boot just issue:

```
# systemctl enable disable-usb-wakeup.service
```

And you should be good to go.